# Gson to json string conversion

Tags: java, json, gson

Hello all I am setting value to an object and then running `gson.tojson(myObject)`

This works fine and the output looks like:

```
{"val1":22,"val2":4,"val3":34,"val4":1046.0,"val5":"hello","val6":true}
```

However I now need my json string to look like

```
{"myJson":  {"val1":22,"val2":4,"val3":34,"val4":1046.0,"val5":"hello","val6":true}}
```

is there a built in way to do this or should I just do sting concat?

Comment: plz come up with a different title

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you just need to get the `JsonTree` and add an inner object to it

```
JsonElement innerObject = gson.toJsonTree(myObject);
JsonObject outerObject = new JsonObject();
outerObject.add("myJson",innerObject);
```

Now, `outerObject` has `innerObject` so you can take it from there, convert it to `String` if you want.

```
String json = outerObject.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a option for that with Gson but you can create a wrapper class for your object :

```
class ObjectWrapper {
    Object myJsonObject;
}
```

And use `gson.toJson()` on the wrapped object.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wrapper class which has your object set in its property "myJson".

```
public class Wrapper {
  <Yourclass> myJson;

  public Wrapper(<Yourclass> obj){
    myJson = obj;
  }
}
```

Afterwards create the JSON based on the Wrapper.